# How to split a string by a list of marks in python?

Tags: python, string

Suppose we have a sentence like: `"ABCDEFG"`, and a list of marks like: `[0,0,1,0,0,0,1]`. What I intends to do is split the source string into segments by using the list of marks: if a character has index `i` in the source string, and by using this index we could get `1` in the list of marks, then this character is the end of a word.

So the source string could be split into `['ABC', 'DEFG']`

How to achieve this in Python? I mean, not the simple way like using a temporary buffer.

Comment: its not at all clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: This question is more appropriate to post in http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ 

And what does that mean by 'something else'? :-)

Comment: Use the `groupby` method in the Python `itertools` documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: @AnthonyKong Thanks for your comment, I think "something else" is redundant here. And I don't know there's a section like codegolf!

Comment: Hi @sachinsaxena, I think the answer from Kumar is the one with temporary buffer, and that's not quite elegant. I think there could be a method like split which could have that kind of functionality.

Comment: If your mark list does not end in a 1, what should happen to the remainder?

Answer (score 0):

We can use simple `for` loop to acheive this -

```
>>> s = "ABCDEFG"
>>> l = [0,0,1,0,0,0,1]
>>>
>>> endlist = []
>>> tsh = ''
>>> for i, ch in enumerate(s):
...     tsh += ch
...     if l[i] == 1:
...             endlist.append(tsh)
...             tsh = ''
...
>>> endlist
['ABC', 'DEFG']
```

Comment: I'm being picky here, but you should append the characters to an array, and then `join` it at the end.  The way you are doing it now is O(n^2)- appending a character to a string is O(n) where n is the length of the string.

Comment: @James, if there is only one reference to the string, adding to the end of the string is amortized O(1)

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be:

```
temp = "ABCDEFG"
t = [0,0,1,0,0,0,1]
f_i, e_i = 0,0
for index,val in enumerate(t):
    if val:
        e_i = index +1
        print temp[f_i: e_i ]       #Here you can store these as you wish
        f_i = e_i
```

Answer (score 0):

`.index` is probably the fastest way to find the `1`s. Also allows you to slice the source string directly

```
s = "ABCDEFG"
L = [0,0,1,0,0,0,1]

pos = 0
res = []
while True:
    try:
        idx = L.index(1, pos) + 1
    except ValueError:
        break
    res.append(s[pos: idx])
    pos = idx

print(res)
```

Comment: I really love your idea! However, is there any reference about "index is the fastest why to find 1s"?

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer:

```
l = [0,0,1,0,0,0,1]
s = 'ABCDEFG'
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(l) if x == 1]
t = 0
a = []
for i in indices:
    a.append(s[t:i+1])
    t = i+1
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variation on a theme.

```
marks = [0,0,1,0,0,0,1]
sentence = 'ABCDEFG'

output = []
last_index = 0

for index, mark in enumerate(marks):
    if mark:
        output.append(sentence[last_index:index+1])
        last_index = index+1

print(output)
```